# Rewriting Root Directory Path "/" for Javascript

Tags: javascript, directory

We can modify the document root directory path for PHP using

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "to/some/new/directory";
//Now the "/" which represent the ^(above) path
```

in .htaccess we have

```
RewriteBase "/to/some/new/directory"
```

Now, I need to modify the root directory path to use in javascript. How to do it?

Currently, I am declaring a variable containing static path to the my personalized root directory and using it as

```
var root = "../to/new/path";
document.location = root+"/somepage.php";
```

## Scenario

I think i should tell a little bit about the scenario, for you guys to catch my idea

Default Web Root Directory

```
http_docs/
```

inside it contain a main folder

```
http_docs/application <-- contains the actual application
http_docs/js <-- contains the script
http_docs/index.html
```

Now, the application also contains ajax feature for updating, editing, loading new content, or other resources, which if accessed at "/" will represent at /some/path/i/called not /application/some/path/i/called,

To come around this problem 
I can define a static variable like

```
var root = "application/";
```

and use it somewhere like

```
$.post(....., function(data) { $(body).append("<img src='"+root+"resources/img1.jpg"); });
```

But for a single use, defining the path as static, might not be a big deal, but, when the application grows, and certain modification would cause me to change all the paths i give in the js part. I thought, it would be sensible, just like, I do it in PHP, using `<img src="/resources/img1.jpg" />`

I tried my best to explain this question, if still is not understandable, please community, lets help them understand. I welcome you to edit my question.

Comment: What is the question? What do you mean by "modify the root directory"?

Comment: Both of them deal on the Server-Side. So whats the deal you want to settle with JS?

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug, I dont know how much more clear than telling you that I want to the modify root directory path for use in javascript

Comment: And what is a "root directory path" in JavaScript?

Comment: @Starx why do you want to change the url for the client. Why not have it just be `example.com/` your other relative urls should just work.

Comment: @Jan Hančič, the path represented by "/", which generally denotes to `http_docs` in some server, or `public_html` in some server, or when the javascript is accessing, the `example.com/` path

Comment: @Raynos, the main reason the path `example.com/` and my actual directory, which I use as root, using PHP / .htaccess are different.

Comment: @Starx this is a problem that should be fixed using proper server-side routing not hacking the javascript.

Comment: @Raynos, I hope defining a new directory as root would not be technically called as hacking, On the contrary, ... I just want to keep a similar path index, through the entire web application. Just trying to make my framework, more simpler

Comment: @Starx the main issue is that Apache should redirect the requesst for "/resources/img1.jpg" to "/application/resources/img1.jpg". Don't use javascript for this, set apache up properly.

Comment: @Raynos, it is already doing that, but I should be able to do the same using Javascript as well. Are you suggesting to return the path, from the ajax request as well?

Comment: @Starx yes so redirect resources/js/foo.js to application/resources/js/foo.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDITED: Trying to answer the updated question**
Assuming the JavaScript is called included from the index.html file, if you insert a img tag and use relative urls, they will be relative to the path of the index file. So `<img src='application/resources/img1.jpg'>` would work just fine. If the script should work for several sublevels (e.g. if the page "application/etc/etc2/somePage.html" needs images from "application/resources/")it may be easier to use absolute urls, and you could include a javascript block on every page generated by php that holds the absolute url to the "root" of the application, like:

```
<!-- included by php in all html pages, e.g. in defautlHeadter.php -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   var rootUrl = "<?= getTheRootUrl() ?>";
</script>
```

Where `getTheRootUrl()` is a method or server variable that gives the root url you need. If the url is translated/remapped (by apache etc. outside of what is visible to php) you may need to hardcode the root url in the php method but at least it will be only one file to change if you ever change the root directory.

Then you can use the root url to specify absolute paths anywhere in the application/website using `rootUrl + "/some/relative/path"` in anywhere in the application.

Comment: Ok, I will try to rephrase my question then

Comment: This anwer is not helpful to me, in anyway... -1

Comment: Why do you think, this answer is useful? @Voter, please, i would like to know... how is this answer useful to my question

Comment: I answered the best I could on how the original question was phrased... I've updated my answer now that you updated your question.

Comment: @Starx it deserves an upvote merely to counteract your highly negative attitude.

Comment: I am already using the absolute URLs Please see my question from the begining, I am already using absolute path. your assumptions also fails this time, the index.html is not the only file, that contains the js. new pages will be loaded from other folders as well, also what you told about sub levels, is correct.

Comment: @Raynos, it's  a pity you thought so, but I am just doing what SO is suppose to do, vote up useful answers and vote down unuseful answer. A user of your reputation voting me down and stating it as a negative attitude... well... no words... However I appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug, I think as per the comments, I owe you an apology, for sounding rude.

Comment: @Starx: I'm not offended, I started off slightly sarcastic myself... anyway I've re-edited my answer, hopefully more helpful now?

Answer (score -1):

I once made something like this, to set

```
window.app_absolute = '<?php echo GetRelativePath(dirname(__FILE__)); ?>'
```

I also use something like this

```
static function GetRelativePath($path)
{
    $dr = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; //Probably Apache situated

    if (empty($dr)) //Probably IIS situated
    {
        //Get the document root from the translated path.
        $pt = str_replace('\\\\', '/', Server::GetVar('PATH_TRANSLATED',
            Server::GetVar('ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED')));
        $dr = substr($pt, 0, -strlen(Server::GetVar('SCRIPT_NAME')));
    }

    $dr = str_replace('\\\\', '/', $dr);

    return substr(str_replace('\\', '/', str_replace('\\\\', '/', $path)), strlen($dr));
}
```

... Something along those lines, hacked up for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail on your answer. `Something along those lines` ?????????????

Comment: Sorry, I wrote some php but it was erased by the filter. I've updated the answer with some more details.

Comment: So, then what will `window.app_absolute` contain? Current files, relative path I think

Comment: The publicly translated directory of the given __FILE__'s directory. This will however not work too well with aliases in apache like /~user/ folders and such and I've always just had to specify those by hand at an application level.